# How is RainMeter able to keep showing on desktop when Win+D is pressed?

Tags: windows, winapi, electron

I'm trying to build an Electron app like RainMeter which shows some widgets on the desktop. Considering the performance, I choose to create a transparent fullscreen window as the widget container.

How can I keep it on the desktop when the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Win+D</kbd> is triggered? I've tried `electron-disable-minimize`, which places the widget window as a child of `ShellDll_DefView`. It works with some other issues (*the transparent part of the window can be clicked and focused*).

Is there a better solution for disabling window minimization by <kbd>Win+D</kbd>?